# Cython bdist_egg with setuptools creates invalid package

Tags: python, cython, setuptools

I am attempting to compile a *.pyx file.  It uses some definitions and constants inside a `__init__.py` in the same directory. The project structure is:

```
setup.py
Foo/__init__.py
Foo/Foo.pyx
```

and the setup command is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy

setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_module = [ Extension(name='Foo', sources=['Foo/Foo.pyx']) ],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
    name='Foo',
    packages=['Foo'],
    zip_safe=True
)
```

Problem arises when the egg is built and deployed. The resultant egg has the following structure:

```
Foo.so                  
Foo.py                  
Foo/__init__.py
```

Now, `Foo.py` contains some dynamic import code that basically imports the *.so file. However, because of the presence of `Foo/__init__.py`, `import Foo` attempts to import symbols only from `__init__.py`, which contains just some constants (all the relevant code is actually in `Foo.so`).

I've hacked around this issue by pasting all the definitions from `__init__.py` into `Foo.pyx`, but I'm trying to figure out what a proper solution might be.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down my problem to an extraneous argument to the `setup()` command. Judging by the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html, I do not need the `packages=['Foo']` argument, and in fact that's what's causing it to create the inner `Foo` package that's messing everything up.